Are question related to regulation on topic?
Quants/modellers working in risk management often face questions how to interpret certain bits of supervisory regulation. Wording in official regulation texts can be vague, leaving many degrees of freedom on how a particular model should be developed. Are questions about supervisory regulation in quantitative model development on topic? If not, is there any other forum for them?

Yes, looks OK to me as long as context is provided and that the topic is indeed about quant modeling.
